# How to factorize the model in controllers?

Tags: spring-mvc, model, controller, autowired, factorization

Using Spring MVC, is there any way to factorize the `org.springframework.ui.Model`, in order to not to have to specify it in the method parameters within any controller?

In other words, I'm currently doing it like this:

```
public abstract class AbstractController {

    @Autowired
    protected MultipartHttpServletRequest request;

}

@Controller
public class SigninController extends AbstractController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/signin", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String signin(@ModelAttribute User user, Model model) {
        // do stuff with user (parameter)
        // do stuff with model (parameter) <--
        // do stuff with request (attribute)
        return "/signin/index";
    }

}
```

And I would like to do like that:

```
public abstract class AbstractController {

    @Autowired
    protected MultipartHttpServletRequest request;

    @Autowired
    protected Model model;

}

@Controller
public class SigninController extends AbstractController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/signin", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String signin(@ModelAttribute User user) {
        // do stuff with user (parameter)
        // do stuff with model (attribute) <--
        // do stuff with request (attribute)
        return "/signin/index";
    }

}
```

But when calling the URL, an exception is thrown:

```
...Could not autowire field: protected org.springframework.ui.Model...
...No matching bean of type [org.springframework.ui.Model] found for dependency...
```

I got the same error when using `org.springframework.ui.ModelMap`.

Any solution of genious?

Thanks for helping :)

Comment: @sp00m..i am just curious to know the purpose of doing this.

Comment: @raddykrish I just find my controllers more readable and I'm not kind of methods with n parameters (with 3 < n < ∞). And also because AFAIK, I believe that factorization is the good and expansion is the bad :)

Comment: I understand your point. My thought is, since Model and ModelMap are not Spring managed classes, i wonder whether we can do this Autowiring.

Comment: But both of them are located in the `org.springframework.ui` package though, so I think there must be a way to do that trick. I'll keep searching by myself while waiting for the transcendental solution :)

Comment: By the way, the solution may not be necessarily using the `@Autowired` annotation.

Comment: One way which i can think of is define the ModelMap as a bean in the application context xml and inject in the controller using setter injection, but that will create a confusion of xml and annotation based configuration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a solution. I'm not sure the game is worth it, but it works :)

First, add those stuff in your `AbstractController`:

```
public abstract class AbstractController {

    @Autowired
    protected MultipartHttpServletRequest request;

    protected ModelMap model;

    public void setModel(ModelMap model) {
        this.model = model;
    }

    public ModelMap getModel() {
        return model;
    }

}
```

Then, create an interceptor implementing `org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerInterceptor` like this one:

```
public class UserContextInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor {

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws ServletException {
        if (handler instanceof AbstractController) {
            AbstractController controller = (AbstractController) handler;
            controller.setModel(new ModelMap());
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, ModelAndView modelAndView) {
        if (handler instanceof AbstractController && modelAndView != null) {
            AbstractController controller = (AbstractController) handler;
            modelAndView.addAllObjects(controller.getModel());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void afterCompletion(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, Exception ex) throws Exception {
    }

}
```

Finally, add these lines in your `applicationContext.xml`:

```
<mvc:interceptors>
    <bean class="path.to.my.just.created.UserContextInterceptor" />
</mvc:interceptors>
```

And of course, make your controllers implementing your `AbstractController`.

Here it is! You need to specify neither your `request` nor your `model` within your controllers methods parameters anymore :) I'm not really convinced of the usefulness of that trick though, but yeah. If it can make maniacal developers happier :)

Still open to *easier* solutions though.

Comment: Did you check my previous comments. I have mentioned something like this (but not throught interceptors) . Anyways good to know this solution.

Comment: Yes, sorry for not having answered. I tried it. The good point was that the exception wasn't thrown anymore, so the bean was correctly autowired (no `NullPointerException` was thrown as well). But the model wasn't sent to the view, so I hadn't access to my attributes from my JSP pages. But thanks anyway for your answers!

Comment: Ohh...but i think still you can send the model to the view by return ModelView instead of String, since in your interceptor you have used like `modelAndView.addAllObjects(controller.getModel());`, the same can be used in the controller as well. Anyways good to know that you tried the option i mentioned as well. Thanks!!!